# Simple Python script - import command not executing once python is started

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, project

I am having a novice level issue with a python script that I have been working on. Essentially I create a mouse jiggler application that runs when the batch file is opened. When I open the file I can install pyautogui and start python but the next import and while commands do not execute.

Could someone help me fix this issue?

```
Batch script
pip install pyautogui #(works)<br>
python #(works)<br>
import pyautogui, time #(does not work)<br>
while True: pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50, duration = 1) time.sleep(240) #(does not work)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0TAE.png)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: the commands you have there are bash commands, so you are trying to execute `import` as a bash command. Create a python script `do_stuff.py`, copy paste inside the 4th and 5th line and change 3rd line to `python do_stuff.py`. It will launch the python script

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
python -m "import pyautogui, time; while True: pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50, duration = 1) time.sleep(240)"
```

Since you are running this script from the batch script (as you've mentioned above) your batch program can't input scripts to the python interpreter.